# Calculating the IP after the nth range

Tags: math, ip

I have an IP address 10.0.2.0

The next IP after a block of 64 (10.0.2.0 to 10.0.2.63) is 10.0.2.64
After that (10.0.2.64  to 10.0.2.127 ) 10.0.2.128 etc

How do I calculate the nth?

I had assumed roughly

a = (n*64) mod 256
b = 255/n

10.0.2+b.a

Comment: Are you asking how to calculate the representation of N in powers of 256?

Comment: N will represent the nth tenant. I need to calculate the starting IP for that tenant.

So n= 1 10.0.2.0
n = 2 10.0.2.64
n = 3 10.0.2.128
n = 5 10.0.2.192
n = 6 10.0.3.0

Comment: I assumed it would be a simple mod problem but  for n = 5...   5 * 64 =320
320 mod 255 = 65
10.0.3.65 (2 out)

Comment: Please [edit] to elaborate those problems in the question itself. Show how you tried to use modulo and integer division. Explain the shortcomings that had. I still believe that intger-dividing and modulo or powers of 256 are the solution and do not get what stops you from using them.

Comment: Your formula is fine. It's really as simple as treating the IPv4 address as a 32 bit integer and adding 64 to it to get the next block. Then treat the number as 4 bytes again to obtain the IP address. This is very easy in most languages.

Comment: Before I read your comment I implemented this:

function incrementIP (ip, nIps){
 var nums = ip.split(".");
 doit(nums,3,nIps);
 return nums.join(".");
}

function doit (ip, index, nIps){
 if(index==-1) return;
 var remainder = (nIps) % 256; 
 var divider = Math.floor((nIps)/256); 

 var val = parseInt(ip[index]);

 if(val+remainder <256) {
  val = val +remainder;
 } else {
  val = (val +remainder) -256
  divider +=1;
 }
 ip[index] = val;
 doit(ip, index-1,divider);

}

Which is clearly very messy. Will go with your approach instead :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's the final solution (in JavaScript):

```
function incrementIp(ip,nips){
  var input = ip.split(".");
  var ip = (input[0] << 24) | (input[1] << 16) | (input[2] << 8) | (input[3] << 0);
  ip+=nips; 
  return (ip>>24 & 0xff )+ "." + (ip>>16 &0xff) + "." +( ip>>8 &0xff) + "." + (ip & 0xff);
}
```